# Matlab, smaller duration histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I have this histogram plot. It show histogram for every 100 duration. I want to show histogram in smaller duration for example every 10 .How can I do this in Matlab?Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
hist(data,nbins)
```

to specify the number of bins. Default is 10, so if you want to have it split not by 100 but by 10 use:

```
hist(data,100)
```

Comment: Thanks. The figure reflect the information very bad.Is there any better way to represent histogram of my data?

Comment: I dont know what your data exactly look like, but you could try addin g logaritmic scale to your histogram. Try set(gca,'xscale','log')

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @slezadav, if you want to set a given bin width (10 in your example) you can use something like

```
hist(data,5:10:995)
```

Using a vector as the second argument of `hist` specifies bin centers.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the docs:
use the nbins argument of the hist function:

```
rng(0,'twister') 
data = randn(1000,1);
figure
nbins = 5;
hist(data,nbins)
```

you can check this by changing the parameter of nbins.

See also here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/hist.html