# Matlab,better histogram representation

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

This question is related to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854192/matlab-smaller-duration-histogram).
I have this histogram but as you see it is very difficult to compare the bares. Is there any method to better represent the information for better comparison by eyes?Thanks. 
[image: Picture]

Comment: ...zoom in on the section of interest?

Comment: @Dan Thanks :). I mean better representation at a glance. Is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want logarithmic Y/X-axis. this is possible by using a workaround, that is explained here:

[Why does my histogram become incorrect when I change the y-axis scaling to 'log'?](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-2ZUTKK/?solution=1-2ZUTKK)
You cannot just use the 'Yscale','log' , because:

> the bars are incorrectly displayed; the histogram bars either become lines or disappear entirely.